# Regex capturing words that have at least one lowercase letter

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture words in a string like:

```
1vTvFpU
KOoy6Cc
```

With regex pattern:

```
\b(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){1,})[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_.]{7,7}\b
```

But I have a problem because it also matches words like:

```
FDSFDFI
WEWEFDP
RRRRRRR
```

In a string:

```
FDSFDFI sdfdfdf
WEWEFDP traliii
RRRRRRR sdfdfdf
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `\S*` instead of `.*` inside the lookahead. Because when you include `.*?` inside the lookahead, it checks for atleast one lower-case letter  for the whole line not for the word.

```
\b(?=(?:\S*?[a-z]))[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_.]{7}\b
```

`{7,7}` is equal to `{7}`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yH3eV5/2)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a lookahead to do that, character classes suffice:

```
[^\Wa-z]*+\w+
```

Then checks the string length with php (for example with `array_filter`).